# Change debug design forms within aproject VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, debugging

This probably has a one click solution, i know debugging web pages in VS2010 just needs to set as start page to debug the given window, but i can't seem to change it in windows forms. Keeps debugging the old one, any clues to how to set debugging form?? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Program.cs file and you can set the Startup Form there:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

To change this, Right  Click the Project > Properties and set the startup object there.

Comment: @SpencerHire There is a holo checkbox next to each answer, ticking it saves peoples time by knowing the problem has been solved AND it gives you a couple of points too! You would have noticed by now that you cant upvote or downvote because you dont have over 10pts. Well... I just fixed that for you, welcome to http://Stackoverflow.com